# Which is recommended form control to use in SharePoint?

Tags: 2010, asp.net, visual-web-part, html, application-pages

When trying to develop Web Part or Application page or modifying existing SharePoint application pages like (user.aspx, create.aspx, etc..)

From below list which control is recommended to use

```
<input id="Text1" type="text" />
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<wssawc:InputFormTextBox title="Test" class="ms-long" ID="txttest" Runat="server" />
<SharePoint:InputFormTextBox title="Test" class="ms-long" ID="txttest1" Runat="server" />
```

Moreover what is the difference between among them?

In which way they are working and how much SharePoint resource (memory and performance) are utilized?

Can anyone give me clear understanding?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's not a huge difference for all of them.

3 out of 4 of them are server-side controls. And the `SharePoint:InputFormTextBox` and `wssawc:InputFormTextBox` are the exact same, only the prefix namespace (i.e. `SharePoint`, `wssawc`) is the difference.

`SharePoint/wssawc:InputFormTextBox` has built-in co-operative field validation, the others don't. That's the main difference and why they are recommended.

Comment: Let assume i am going to develop application page. Can i use SharePoint:* or wssawc:*.  which make any seance or do i need to follow any structure in my way of coding?

Comment: namespace mean? it will reflect any changes in rendering? but i could not found any changes in visual. Pls educate me.

Comment: @ThirusangurajaVenkatesan I believe you can use the `SharePoint:` prefix. What I mean with *prefix namespace* is, in your application pages (.aspx) in the top you will find code like this: `<%@ Register TagPrefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>`.